# Hazelcast, null urn value in task on other member

Tags: distributed-computing, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast IScheduledExecutorService and submitting task on this IScheduledExecutorService from one node, which will be then distributed and executed on other cluster member.

Node-1 : created task (callable) and submitted to IScheduledExecutorService.
Node-1 : while sumbmiting task takes future and generate handler urn(future.getHandler().toUrn()) and set urn string in to task.

Now when job is scheduled on Node other than 1, I try to fetch urn value and it give value as null, though it was set in task.

Why urn has become null in the task when task is executed from other cluster member?

Answer (score 3):

The URN is used to construct `ScheduledTaskHandler` again if you need the future instance later. See the example below:

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IScheduledExecutorService executorService = hazelcast.getScheduledExecutorService("myScheduler");

IScheduledFuture<Integer> future = executorService.schedule(
        new ScheduledClusterTask(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

String urn = future.getHandler().toUrn();
ScheduledTaskHandler handler = ScheduledTaskHandler.of(urn);
IScheduledFuture<Integer> scheduledFuture = executorService.getScheduledFuture(handler);
```

The `urn` can be generated after the task is submitted, and can be saved/persisted to access the future instance later.

If you are setting the URN to the task instance after the task submission, you cannot get it when the task is executed from other cluster member. Because the task is serialized and sent to the cluster whilst submission, and the alterations after submission isn't reflected to the submitted task.